# Replay button with counter

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having some trouble getting my playCount to work properly with my replay command.

The goal is to have a button pop up at the end, that gives the option to replay the animation. After the 3rd play, the button should no longer appear.

Currently it continues to show the button even after 3 plays.
The command to tell the replay button to appear is supposed to only trigger if the playCount is less than 3. The trace is coming back showing more that 3 plays, but the button still appears.

I'm not sure where the problem is.

Here's the problematic snippet of code (or where I think the problem is):

```
// replay button
if(playCount < 3)
{
    trace(playCount);
    tl.from(replayBtn, .5, {alpha:0})
    replayBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, replay);

}

function replay(event:MouseEvent):void{
            tl.restart()
            // add one to playCount
            playCount++;
            trace(playCount);

}
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Zf1Q3DOqwmYzg4QjVnSGNnSlk/view?usp=sharing) is a link to my files.

Answer (score 0):

create a new function called `removebutton` then add an `if` condition

```
if(playCount >= 3)
 {
  trace(playCount);
  replayBtn.enabled = false ;
  replayBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, replay);
 }
```

the reason is that your button is enabled and its still functioning , couldnt check your code though , but this might work ,

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out so I'll just leave this here

```
  function replay(event:MouseEvent):void{
playCount++;
trace(playCount);

if(playCount < 2) {
    //replay the function if there are less than 2 plays on the playcount
tl.restart();
} else {
    //if there are not less than 2 plays, replay but the button invisible
tl.restart();
replayBtn.visible = false;
}
}
```

from what I originally had, I changed the function to an if-else clause. Instead of trying to make it not play the last step when the play count was about 2 (since it will replay 1 more time after it hits 2), I set it to restart if there are less than 2 counts and restart with the button invisible if there isn't less than 2 (the button is being hidden using alpha in the rest of the base animation)